# Tooltipster not displaying for last array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, arrays

I have a simple MVC program that passes a list of user to my view, and inside the view i've looped through the array and assigned each users name to title attribute in an anchor tag. I'm using the tool tipster plugin to display the title(users name) when a user hovers over each link. However, for some reason the last item from the array is not assigned a 'tooltipstered' class.

html

```
    <div class="map" style="height: 1114px; width:960px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; background: url('/Content/MAP.png') no-repeat top center;"></div>
```

javascript

```
 $(function() {

        var allData = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AllDeskData));

        var datatest;

        function getDesks(coordsArr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < coordsArr.length; i++) {
                var element = $("<a href='#' class='deskBtn tooltip' title='" + coordsArr[i].Name + "' data-name='" + coordsArr[i].UserName + "'></a>");

                $('.tooltip').tooltipster();

                $(element).on('click', function() {
                    var user = $(this).attr("data-name");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/GetUserData",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { user: user },
                        success: function(data) {
                            //console.log(data.photos[0].value);
                            $(".desk-info-box").animate({
                                "margin-top": "0px"
                            }, 400);
                            $(".map .overlay").fadeIn(300);
                            $(".desk-info-data .name").text(data.displayName);
                            $(".desk-info-data .followers").text("who has " + data.followerCount + " followers");
                            $(".desk-info-data .email").text("email: " + data.jive.username + ".");
                            $(".desk-img").css({ 
                                'background-image' : 'url(' + '/Content/gopi_desk.jpg' + ')',
                                'background-size' : '100% 260px',
                                'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'
                            });
                            $(".user-image").attr("src",data.photos[0].value);
                        }
                    });

                });

                $(".hide-detail").on("click",function(){
                    $(".desk-info-box").animate({
                        "margin-top": "-425px"
                    }, 400);
                });


                $(element).css({
                    "top": coordsArr[i].DeskYCoord,
                    "left": coordsArr[i].DeskXCoord
                }).appendTo(".map");
            }
        }

        getDesks(allData);

        /* $(".deskBtn").on("click", function() {

        });*/

    });
```

I can't understand why the last item would not have that class assigned to it.

Comment: Where is `tooltipstered` class in your code ?

Comment: The tooltipstered class is dynamically created.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you calling `$('.tooltip').tooltipster();` for every element and not after you've created them all?

Comment: I thought I needed to call it once the anchor tag was created, on each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the tooltip after all elements appended,

```
function getDesks(coordsArr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < coordsArr.length; i++) {
                var element = $("<a href='#' class='deskBtn tooltip' title='" + coordsArr[i].Name + "' data-name='" + coordsArr[i].UserName + "'></a>");



                $(element).on('click', function() {
                    var user = $(this).attr("data-name");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/GetUserData",
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { user: user },
                        success: function(data) {
                            //console.log(data.photos[0].value);
                            $(".desk-info-box").animate({
                                "margin-top": "0px"
                            }, 400);
                            $(".map .overlay").fadeIn(300);
                            $(".desk-info-data .name").text(data.displayName);
                            $(".desk-info-data .followers").text("who has " + data.followerCount + " followers");
                            $(".desk-info-data .email").text("email: " + data.jive.username + ".");
                            $(".desk-img").css({ 
                                'background-image' : 'url(' + '/Content/gopi_desk.jpg' + ')',
                                'background-size' : '100% 260px',
                                'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'
                            });
                            $(".user-image").attr("src",data.photos[0].value);
                        }
                    });

                });

                $(".hide-detail").on("click",function(){
                    $(".desk-info-box").animate({
                        "margin-top": "-425px"
                    }, 400);
                });


                $(element).css({
                    "top": coordsArr[i].DeskYCoord,
                    "left": coordsArr[i].DeskXCoord
                }).appendTo(".map");
            }
$('.tooltip').tooltipster();
        }
```